# Code Coverage=0%

Tags: trigger, code-coverage, code

my developer createed the following trigger and Apex Test Class. For some reason, the coverage is 0%. I need to deploy it ASAP and he already left for the rest of the week. any help is highly appreciated!

Trigger

```
    trigger ContentDocumentLinkArchiverTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (after delete) {

    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            List<Id> dealDocumentsId = new List<Id>();   
            for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : Trigger.old) {
                Id relatedToId = cdl.LinkedEntityId;
                if(relatedToId.getsobjecttype().getDescribe().getName() == 'Deal_Document__c'){
                    dealDocumentsId.add(relatedToId);

                }
            }

            List<Deal_Document__c> deals = [Select Id, Document_Archived_By_OwnBackup__c From  Deal_Document__c where id IN: dealDocumentsId];
            for(Deal_Document__c deal : deals){
                deal.Document_Archived_By_OwnBackup__c = true;
            }

            update deals;
         }
     }




}
```

Apex Test Class:

```
    @isTest
class ContentDocumentLinkArchiverHandlerTest{

    @isTest
    private static void testUpdateDealDocumentWithArchivedFiles(){
         Account dealAccount = new Account(
             Name='Test'
         );
         insert dealAccount;

         Contact dealContact = new Contact(
             FirstName='Test', 
             LastName='Test', 
             AccountId=dealAccount.Id
         );
         insert dealContact;

         Opportunity deal = New Opportunity(
             Contact__c=dealContact.Id, 
             CloseDate=Date.Today(), 
             AccountId=dealAccount.Id, 
             Name='Test', 
             StageName='Initial Review');
         insert deal;

         Deal_Document__c dealDocument = new Deal_Document__c(
             Deal__c=deal.Id
         );
             insert dealDocument;


         ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion(
            Title = 'Test',
            PathOnClient = 'Test.jpg',
            VersionData = blob.valueof('Test Content Data')     
        );
        insert cv;

            ContentVersion contentVersionSelect = [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :cv.Id LIMIT 1];
            List<ContentDocument> documents = [SELECT Id, Title, LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument];

             ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
             contentlink.LinkedEntityId=dealDocument.id;  
             contentlink.ShareType= 'I';               
             contentlink.ContentDocumentId=documents[0].Id;
             contentlink.Visibility = 'AllUsers'; 
             insert contentlink;
             System.assertEquals(documents.size(), 1);

             delete documents;

            Deal_Document__c  dealDocumentAfterUpdate = [Select Id, Document_Archived_By_OwnBackup__c From Deal_Document__c Where Id=:dealDocument.id Limit 1][0];
            System.assertEquals(dealDocumentAfterUpdate.Document_Archived_By_OwnBackup__c, true);




    }


}
```

[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the test show that it passes, or is there an error message?

Comment: as you can see above, I added a screenshot, the code coverage on the trigger is 0/11 - 0%

Comment: @LihodRachmilevitch You don't receive code coverage for tests that fail. If you run the test, what do the results actually say?

Comment: @LihodRachmilevitch while this certainly isn't the answer you're hoping for, I think this is documented / expected behavior, your test class will never cover that code. See my answer for more info.

Comment: Pro tip `if(relatedToId.getsobjecttype().getDescribe().getName() == 'Deal_Document__c')` can be simplified to `if (relatedToId.getSobjectType() == Deal_Document__c.SobjectType)`

Answer (score 4):

This outcome is explained by considering the relationships between ContentDocument and ContentDocumentLink.

It's documented Salesforce behavior that cascade-deletes do not invoke apex triggers on any of the cascade-deleted children, only on the item(s) that were physically deleted.

When you delete a ContentDocument, any related ContentDocumentLinks aren't necessary anymore and are cascade deleted.

Therefore, Salesforce will (natively) never run a delete trigger on ContentDocumentLink when you delete a ContentDocument. Unless you were to explicitly delete a ContentDocumentLink directly, this trigger would never fire.

**More Info:**

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008x2FIAQ

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm

> **Some operations don’t invoke triggers.**
>
> Triggers are invoked for data
>   manipulation language (DML) operations that the Java application
>   server initiates or processes. Therefore, some system bulk operations
>   don't invoke triggers. Some examples include:
>
> - **Cascading delete
>     operations. Records that did not initiate a delete don't cause trigger
>     evaluation.**

---

If your intention is to run this logic when your users (or integrations) delete a **ContentDocument**, you should refactor the trigger to run on delete of **ContentDocument** rather than ContentDocumentLink, and if you need to work with the ContentDocumentLink child records then you would query for them in the ContentDocument trigger.

Sorry for the bad news.

You can vote for this idea to have this "fixed", but it would require Salesforce to change its stance on cascade delete trigger invocation: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LqYeQAK

Comment: The relationship from `ContentDocument -> ContentDocumentLink` is definitely CascadeDelete, no need to speculate

Comment: Fair point, I didn't have time to dig into the relationship so I wasn't comfortable being concrete, but in retrospect, it really wouldn't make sense to leave a Link behind if the associated Document was gone. I'll edit the answer slightly